# How to make Slide show for Apple iphone

Tags: iphone

HI anyone Please let me know i need to Make a Slide show Application which can have 10 images and i need to keep all these Images in a Slide show manner

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use the [Briefs framework](http://giveabrief.com/), which makes it trivial to take a series of images and use them to make an interactive slideshow application.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [TapLynx](http://inessential.com/2009/10/14/taplynx_1_0)

Comment: It looks like a good solution for non-devs but take note that the production license costs 599 USD per application.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have slideshow of 10 slides on your iPhone then there are a few export options that you can use from [Keynote](http://www.apple.com/iwork/keynote/) that will give you a really good looking slide show.